# BOOST Hardening Guide (Preprocessor Macros)

Tags: boost, boost-preprocessor

I'm having a hard time determining what preprocessor macros I should use with Boost for (1) debug instrumentation (such as checked iterators) and (2) security related items.

All I can seem to find is [Preprocessor Metaprogramming](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html) (linked from www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/).

UPDATE (02-18-2013): I found [Boost Macro Reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html), but it lacks anything related to debugging or security.

Does anyone know of a list of available preprocessor macros for debugging and security or a hardening guide?

Comment: The answer is likely specific to a boost library, which ones are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks @Sam. As for which library - its all of them. Boost supposedly has coding requirements, quality checks, etc. So I expect they have something thing similar to GCC's `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` or Microsoft's `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`. Or does Boost pickup on those macros (and honor others such as `DEBUG` and `_DEBUG`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any equivalents I'm aware of in any of the boost libraries.  A few of them respect `NDEBUG` and make optimisations based on that (and there are also some asserts `NDEBUG` would disable), so setting `NDEBUG` for release but not debug would seem to be expected (whether leaving `NDEBUG` undefined for release counts as "hardening" I don't know).  But certainly none of the libs have options beyond that which give them any extra armour-plating or debuggability.

How the boost libraries should interact with Microsoft's `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` and particularly `_SECURE_SCL` is a recurring debate see e.g [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-build-should-we-not-define-SECURE-SCL-0-by-default-for-all-msvc-toolsets-td2654710.html), [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.build/17824/match=high+cost) and [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2008/09/20072.php) (for the "header-only" libraries it doesn't make much difference; it's more of a problem making sure provided DLLs are compatible with what integrators expect, and there's no universal agreement on whether MS defaults for these options should be used or not as many people are suspicious of the performance overheads).

Comment: Thanks @timday. I'll make a note at  [C-Based Toolchain Hardening](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/C-Based_Toolchain_Hardening#Additional_Macros). Jeff

Comment: Is your name "Tim Day"? I would like to cite you on the OWASP article.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  Now I've seen the context, adding a few more links above.